# METEOR: Fail to send email to multiple users

Tags: email, meteor

I need to notify all users through their email when I have new post

**server/methods.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendNewsletter: function(doc) {
    var pipeline = [
      {$group: {_id:"$emails.address"}}
    ];
    var to = Meteor.users.aggregate(pipeline);
    var text = "Title: " + doc.title + "\n\n"
            + "Summary: " + doc.summary + "\n\n\n\n"

    this.unblock();

    // Send the e-mail
    Email.send({
        to: to,
        from: "noreply@domain.com",
        subject: "MyApp - " + doc.title,
        text: text
    });
  }
});
```

When I call sendNewsletter's method in client, I got following warning on my terminal:

```
I20151030-04:16:42.039(7)? Exception while invoking method 'sendNewsletter' RecipientError: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected
I20151030-04:16:42.041(7)?     at Object.Future.wait (/Users/user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.1f0n2l1++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
I20151030-04:16:42.042(7)?     at smtpSend (packages/email/email.js:86:1)
I20151030-04:16:42.042(7)?     at Object.Email.send (packages/email/email.js:176:1)
I20151030-04:16:42.043(7)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (livedata_server.js:1692:12)
I20151030-04:16:42.043(7)?     at livedata_server.js:708:19
I20151030-04:16:42.043(7)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20151030-04:16:42.044(7)?     at livedata_server.js:706:40
I20151030-04:16:42.044(7)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20151030-04:16:42.044(7)?     at livedata_server.js:704:46
I20151030-04:16:42.044(7)?     - - - - -
I20151030-04:16:42.045(7)?     at SMTPClient._actionRCPT (/Users/user/.meteor/packages/email/.1.0.7.11df8pa++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/simplesmtp/lib/client.js:909:27)
I20151030-04:16:42.045(7)?     at SMTPClient._onData (/Users/user/.meteor/packages/email/.1.0.7.11df8pa++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/simplesmtp/lib/client.js:329:29)
I20151030-04:16:42.045(7)?     at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:95:17)
I20151030-04:16:42.045(7)?     at CleartextStream.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
I20151030-04:16:42.046(7)?     at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:92:17)
I20151030-04:16:42.046(7)?     at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
I20151030-04:16:42.046(7)?     at _stream_readable.js:420:7
I20151030-04:16:42.046(7)?     at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
```

Does anyone know how to send email to multiple recipients? thank You,,,,

Comment: hi @MichelFloyd.. yes that's the problem.,, i have asked solution at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425565/how-to-return-array-of-string-with-mongodb-aggregation

Comment: what do you mean string with comma?

Comment: Oops, never mind. [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email_send) call for a "string or array of strings" so you're on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-write your `server/methods.js` file get the `to` variable hold an array of the email addresses.
Since Meteor doesn't support distinct in MongoDB (yet) which you could simply use in mongo shell as `db.users.distinct("emails.address")`, you can instead

Use three methods in the underscore.js library **[`map()`](http://underscorejs.org/#map)**, **[`flatten()`](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten)** and **[`uniq()`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)** to get the distinct email addresses from the users collection.

First convert the Meteor cursor returned by **[`.find()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find)** to an array by using **[`.fetch()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch)** on your cursor. Example:

```
var users = Users.find({}, { fields: {"emails": true} }).fetch();
```

Then use the **[`map()`](http://underscorejs.org/#map)** method to produces a new array of only email address values within another array by mapping each document in list through a transformation function (iteratee). Define the transformation function as follows

```
var callback = function(doc) {
    var emailAddresses = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < doc.emails.length; i++) {
        emailAddresses.push(doc.emails[i].address);
    }
    return emailAddresses;
};

var emails = _.map(users, callback);
```

You can also use the mongo cursor's **[`map()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/map)** method which is compatible with **[`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to get the arrays directly with your collection:

```
var emails = Users.find({}).map(callback);
```

Flatten the array by using the **[`flatten()`](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten)** to get a usable array then use the **[`uniq()`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)** method to return a bunch of unique arrays as follows:

```
var uniqueEmails = _.uniq(_.flatten(emails));
```

Altogether your code should now have an array of email addresses that you can then send

```
Meteor.methods({
    sendNewsletter: function(doc) {
        var users = Users.find({}, { fields: {"emails": true} }).fetch();
        var callback = function(doc) {
            var emailAddresses = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < doc.emails.length; i++) {
                emailAddresses.push(doc.emails[i].address);
            }
            return emailAddresses;
        };

        var emails = _.map(users, callback);
        var to = _.uniq(_.flatten(emails));
        var text = "Title: " + doc.title + "\n\n"
                + "Summary: " + doc.summary + "\n\n\n\n"

        this.unblock();

        // Send the e-mail
        Email.send({
            to: to,
            from: "noreply@domain.com",
            subject: "MyApp - " + doc.title,
            text: text
        });
    }
});
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var users = [
 {
  "_id" : "ukn9MLo3hRYEpCCty",    
  "emails" : [ 
   {
    "address" : "a@a.com",
    "verified" : false
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id" : "5SXRXraariyhRQACe",    
  "emails" : [ 
   {
    "address" : "b@a.com",
    "verified" : false
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id" : "WMHWxeymY4ATWLXjz",    
  "emails" : [ 
   {
    "address" : "c@a.com",
    "verified" : false
   }
  ]
 }
];

var callback = function(d) {
 var emailAddresses = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < d.emails.length; i++) {
  emailAddresses.push(d.emails[i].address);
 }
 return emailAddresses;
};
var emails = users.map(callback);
var to = _.uniq(_.flatten(emails));

pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(to, null, 4);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: @KarinaL No worries, happy to help.