# How to return array of string with mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to return array of string with mongodb aggregation. I did the following:

```
db.users.aggregate([{$group: {_id:"$emails.address"}}])
```

It return:

```
{ "_id" : [ "a@a.com" ] }
{ "_id" : [ "b@a.com" ] }
{ "_id" : [ "c@a.com" ] }
```

Is there a way to return array of string like this one:

```
["a@a.com","b@a.com","c@a.com"]
```

thank You very much anyone who taking your time for helping me..

**EDIT**

Adding data:

```
{
    "_id" : "ukn9MLo3hRYEpCCty",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-10-24T03:52:11.960Z"),
    "emails" : [
        {
            "address" : "a@a.com",
            "verified" : false
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "5SXRXraariyhRQACe",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-10-24T03:52:12.093Z"),
    "emails" : [
        {
            "address" : "b@a.com",
            "verified" : false
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "WMHWxeymY4ATWLXjz",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-10-24T03:52:12.237Z"),
    "emails" : [
        {
            "address" : "c@a.com",
            "verified" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you post your data

Comment: hi @ScottStensland i have added the data,,,thank You..

Comment: hi r u meaning to return in name with array values pair or just return only in array?

Comment: hi @HaRLoFei just return only in array. any idea??

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `.aggregate()` method always returns `Objects` no matter what you do and that cannot change.

For your purpose you are probably better off using [`.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) instead, which does just return an array of the distinct values:

```js
db.users.distinct("emails.address");
```

Which is exactly your desired output:

```js
["a@a.com","b@a.com","c@a.com"]
```

If you really want to use `.aggregate()` then the tranformation to just the values needs to happen "outside" of the expression in post processing. And you should also be using `$unwind` when dealing with arrays like this.

You can do this with JavaScript `.map()` for example:

```js
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$emails" },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$emails.address" } }
]).map(function(el) { return el._id })
```

Which gives the same output, but the `.map()` does the transformation client side instead of on the server.

Comment: is there a way to make it in server side, as client side mapping will slow down performance

Comment: @ChiDov I've answered doing on mongodb here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46599310/4308032

It will give you an array, but it will be still embedded in object.

Answer (score 29):

What [Blakes Seven has answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33428753/4308032) is right.

> The .aggregate() method always returns Objects no matter what you do
>   and that cannot change.

However, that does not mean you cannot put them in an array and return the array in an object.

I believe that mapping in array in the database itself would be more better, as your node server can still be available to other requests.

```
db.users.aggregate([
     { "$unwind": "$emails" },
     { "$group": { "_id": null, emails:{$push:"$emails.address"} } },
     { "$project":{emails:true,_id:false}}
 ])
```

This will return:

```
{ "emails" : [ "a@a.com", "b@a.com", "c@a.com" ] }
```