# MongoDB aggregate project return an array of _id

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

As we know if we want to get an array of _id we can do:

```
db.collections.distinct("_id");
```

My question is how can I get an array of _id if I need to do a complicate logic with aggregate.
Ex:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate({
        $match : {
            is_register_completed : { $ne : true}
        }
    }
    //other operator like $lookup, $group
    ,
     {
         $project : {_id:1}
    }
     )
```

I get

```
{
"_id" : "1",
"_id" : "2"
}
```

what i want is just like we do distinct

```
{[1,2]}
```

**Updated:**
this is what i try to do with $group

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate({
        $match : {
            is_register_completed : { $ne : true}
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
        _id:null, all:{$addToSet: "$_id"}
        }
     }, {$project: {_id:0,all:1}}
     )
```

but i still get

```
{
all : ["1","2"]
}
```

or I can do `.map(function(el) { return el._id })` after getting

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "_id" : "2"
    }
```

, but the map is client side transformation which I think it will affect the performance.

Comment: Can you please put an "edit" or "update" tag in your question for the newly updated code? My answer might get downvoted under the impression that its already included in your question.

Comment: With `distinct()` you just get an array of elements `[1, 2]` for example, not `{[1, 2]}` as you implied which is obviously invalid JSON. You can manipulate the result you get from the aggregate operation to return the array.

Comment: @chridam yes [1,2] is what i want, like I mention I would not prefer to manipulate the result using map in client side.

Comment: The marked duplicate answers your question

Comment: @chridam I have read that thread before created this question, do you think is it a good way to map it in client side?

Comment: Do as much as you can on the mongodb. Why make the node server busy when you can make the async call to mongodb do the work?

Comment: @DushyantBangal so between mapping in client side and using $group to addToSet , which way do you think it is the best practice?

Comment: according to me, using `$group` with `$push` or `$addToSet` would be more better. Your node server can still be available to other requests.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit:**
Quoting from: [How to return array of string with mongodb aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425565/how-to-return-array-of-string-with-mongodb-aggregation)

> The .aggregate() method always returns Objects no matter what you do
>   and that cannot change.

**Original Answer:**
Try the aggregation framework:

```
db.myCol.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{_id:null, array:{$push:"$_id"}}
    },
    {
        $project:{array:true,_id:false}
    }
])
```

Comment: thanks, for you answer. this is what i used to try too. but i want to know is there a way to return a array of object like we do the db.collections.distinct("_id");

Comment: aggregate will always return an object

Comment: ```
var resultSet = db.getCollection("mycollection").aggregate([
  //optional match I use
  {
    $match: {
      "someField": "target value"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: { _id: null, ids: { $push: "$_id" } }
  },
  {
    $project: { ids: true, _id: false }
  }
]).toArray()
var ids = resultSet[0].ids
print(ids[0])
```