# How to get all the values of a given key in the whole collection in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

One of my mongodb collection is

```
{_id: "1", username: "one"}
{_id: "2", username: "two"}
{_id: "3", username: "three"}
......
{_id: "50", username: "fifty"}
```

I want to query the collection to get the values of all the "username" keys in whole collection as:

```
["one","two","three",.... "fifty"]
```

I've tried this so far and it yields the results as:

```
db.users.find({}, { username: 1, _id: 0 })
// output: [ { username: "one" }, { username: "two" }, ..... ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB aggregate project return an array of \_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599079/mongodb-aggregate-project-return-an-array-of-id)

Comment: @turivishal yes, it is somewhat similar yet, it didn't exactly matches the format that I'm expecting. But anyways it's a simple JS parsing thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the `$group` stage via Aggregation and group all the documents in the collection and push the required value to an array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "usernames": {
        "$push": "$username"
      }
    },
  },
])
```

If you want distinct values of usernames, replace `$push` with `$addToSet` instead.