# output list of values using group by which was done using mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection xyz, i need to find all unique values for column branch without using mongodbs `.distinct` method. I know we can do it via group by, this gives me array of objects as result, but i need array of string as output like ['a', 'b', 'c']. I am not aware of how to format it this way, in mongo query only.

db.getCollection("xyz").aggregate([
{
$group: { "_id": "$branch" },
}
])

Answer (score 0):

The following link contains a similar question to yours. Please refer to the answers there. [How to return array of string with mongodb aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425565/how-to-return-array-of-string-with-mongodb-aggregation)