# Custom return MongoDB aggregate

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to do some testing with MongoDB and I have figured some of the simpler MySQL queries MongoDB. Now, I have this slightly more complex query.

I have this query that tells me if there was a message in a certain period from a determined user:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN count(1) = 0 THEN false ELSE true END AS 'value'
FROM messages m
WHERE m.time BETWEEN 0 AND 1652471890 AND m.user_id = '256f5280-fb49-4ad6-b7f5-65c4329d46e0';
```

Currently I am trying to do this to count the amount and emit a custom value 0/1:

**Current MongoDB Aggregate**

```js
    db.messages.aggregate([
        { $match: 
            {
            $and: [
              {user_id: "256f5280-fb49-4ad6-b7f5-65c4329d46e0"},
              {time: {$gt: 1622471890, $lt: 1822471890}}
            ]
            } 
        },
        { $count: "value"}
    ])
```

**Dataset:**

```json
    [
    {
        "time": 1422471890,
        "user_id": "256f5280-fb49-4ad6-b7f5-65c4329d46e0",
        "message": "This is an example of my db"
    },
    {
        "time": 1622471890,
        "user_id": "256f5280-fb49-4ad6-b7f5-65c4329d46e0",
        "message": "This is an example of my db (1)"
    },
    {
        "time": 1622471890,
        "user_id": "256f5280-fb49-4ad6-b7f5-65c4329d46e0",
        "message": "This is an example of my db (2)"
    },
    {
        "time": 1622471890,
        "user_id": "e194d667-d79f-4262-94b1-ecf4561c9418",
        "message": "This is an example of my db (3)"
    },
    {
        "time": 1922471890,
        "user_id": "256f5280-fb49-4ad6-b7f5-65c4329d46e0"<
        "message": "This is an example of my db (4)"
    }
    ]
```

**Return:**

With this dataset it's returning:

`{ "value" : 2 }`

I'm trying make its return:

If count > 0:
`{ "value": 1 }`

If count <= 0:
`{ "value": 0 }`

Comment: Would be helpful if some sample dataset and corresponding output is given

Comment: I have common data on my db (user_id, message and time). I want to return if exists a determined message in a determined period of time. The return must be 0 or 1.

Comment: no I mean we need your sample json documents and the expected output so we can see what we can help. You can reference the format of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425565/how-to-return-array-of-string-with-mongodb-aggregation)

Comment: @ray Sure! I am sorry, i updated the question. I hope make it better.

Comment: no we still need sampled dataset... That is a portion of your data that we can use to reproduce the issue on our end. You can simply copy the json out of your database and paste it in your question.

Comment: Okay, No problem, I did it. I think it's ok now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need one more `$addFields` stage to apply `$cond` to your `value`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          user_id: "256f5280-fb49-4ad6-b7f5-65c4329d46e0"
        },
        {
          time: {
            $gte: 1622471890,
            $lt: 1822471890
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$count": "value"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "value": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$gt": [
              "$value",
              0
            ]
          },
          "then": "$value",
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "collection",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      value: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      value: {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$value",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NVbxE6E5otJ) for your reference.

Comment: Oh it's close, when not found a document it's returning empty, its not returning a { "value": 0 }, exists one way to reply when a "document not found" ?